# Unable to start mongodb

Tags: mongodb, windows-7

I'm trying to install mongodb on my window 7 machine. When trying to start it by using the mongod command I get this error. dbpath (\data\db) does not exist. I followed the steps ath the [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service). All the folders exist `C:\mongodb\log`, `C:\mongodb\data and` `C:\mongodb\data\db` .
[image]

Comment: [From `Install MongoDB on Windows`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/): "You may specify an alternate path for \data\db with the dbpath setting for mongod.exe, as in the following example:"
`c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db` or you can set `dbpath` through [`Configuration File`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default path is c:\data\db.  You are trying to use c:\mongodb\data\db.

This means you have to use the option --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db for mongod command.

Comment: do I have to specify --dbpath everytime? are their no option to change the default db path?

Answer (score 6):

By default, when we start the mongodb, it looks for the folder `/data/db` (on Mac/Linux) or `C:\data\db` (on windows)...however, during the installation it doesn't create this folder, so when when we run mongodb for the first time, it fails with the error that it can't find `C:\data\db` folder. The solution is to manually create `C:\data\db` folder and then start mongodb. This error can be totally avoided if the mongodb installer can just give an option to choose this folder path and then create it as part of mongodb installation itself.

Answer (score 3):

In windows you might not have permission for your user. And mongo installer could not create it because of lack of Administrative permission for your user.

So in C:\Program Files\MongoDB:

1. Create  a folder named **data**
2. Create a folder named **db** inside the folder **data**
3. Now right click on the data folder and choose **properties**
4. Click **security** tab and select your user there
5. Click the **Full control** select box
6. Click ok, ok, ok ...
7. **important!**   if you don't have the path "**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin**" set in environment variable, please set it.
8. Now go to shell and type : **mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db"**

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2 command Prompts (CMD) at the same time.

First CMD, use the command:
**mongod** (or **mongod --dbpath C:\mongodb\data**)

Second CMD, use the command:
**mongo**

The second will connect in the database. Do not close the first.